# Devise: Users have unique urls, how do I prevent them from using controller action routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my config file I have this line (note: I am using cached_slugs from the slugged gem):

```
match '/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => 'user'
```

How do I prevent users from signing up with routes that are currently being used for controller actions?

For example, a user could sign up with the username 'users' and their profile's unique URL would be http://localhost:3000/users; however, I am using that route for the users#index action. I could always set it so users have to use the traditional way of http://localhost:3000/users/theusernametheychose but I would prefer it the other way for user friendliness sake. Any suggestions on the best way to solve this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a validation to your user model that checks agains the existing routes defined in the application:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  validates_exclusion_of :name, 
                         :in => Rails.application.routes.routes.map {|r| r.path.match(/\/(\w+)\//) }.compact.map{|m| m[1] }.uniq, 
                         :message => "Username %{value} is reserved.

end
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, appreciate the help!